# ActiveRecord bulk insert with has_one

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Did you ever solved a problem of bulk insert of records with nested association?
(with rails insert_all or with the import gem)
example:

```
Dog.import!(array_of_dogs)
```

and

```
Dog.insert_all(array_of_dogs)
```

will not work if a Dog  has owner association as

```
has_one :owner, class_name: Person
```

and expecting to persist all dogs and all their owners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a gem called DutyFree that makes this kind of thing simple.  Imagine having a schema with three tables for categories, subcategories, and restaurants:

```
___________     _____________     _____________
|Category |     |Subcategory|     |Restaurant |
|         |     |           |     |           |
|         |---->|belongs_to |---->|belongs_to |
|         |     |   Category|     |Subcategory|
|         |     |           |     |           |
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯     ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯     ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

This gem intelligently analyses the has_many and belongs_to associations on the models, and based on these relationships identifies how to properly save each imported row across all destination tables.  Either a create or an update is performed based on if the data already exists or not, and it's on a per-table basis, so if for instance the category was already there but not the subcategory or restaurant, then only those two pieces would be added and associated to the proper category.

This specific example can be seen in a test here:
https://github.com/lorint/duty_free/blob/master/spec/models/restaurant_reverse_spec.rb

All you would have to do for your Dog and Person example is after putting the gem in your Gemfile and bundling, open up **bin/rails c** and try a sample export with:

```
Person.df_export
```

It should automatically go across the belongs_to in Person to find their related Dog.  (By the way you might consider switching this association around so the belongs_to is in Dog, and instead of a has_one turn it into a has_many so that one person could have many dogs.  But that's another story for another time.  And if you were to switch it around it would make more sense to do Dog.df_export or Dog.suggest_template.)

If you want to further customise the columns involved, have the gem give you a starter template that can be added right into the Person model with:

```
Person.suggest_template
```

The IMPORT_TEMPLATE hash that it shows contains detail about what columns you want to have unique, such as the person's email or phone number, and perhaps the dog's birthday or something.

Hope all of this helps.

Comment: looks super nice, though I admit can't fully test the solution
will keep it mind for the next challenge
THANK YOU !

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilitys.

1. You remove all constraints and insert all data and add the constraint at the end. This works because at the time of the backup all constraints worked and will do so after the recovery
2. you can only insert one table at a time, so you make an ER Model of your database, look which tables have to be created first so that all Tables that are in the hierarchy above can be created with a partner table that is already created withpout. And so on till you reach the end. the ER Model is not absolutely needed, but in big databases with lots of tables, it helps to keep order and with the right program you can move  teh tables around to find the right recovery order.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to insert associations separately.

I have explained how i solved this issue in my blog - https://medium.com/@muralidharanashish/bulk-import-in-ruby-on-rails-8546fed74f4